# laravel terminable middleware gets called before returning response

Tags: laravel, middleware

I use postman to query my laravel API and the terminate method in my middleware gets called before postman receives the result:

Route

```
 Route::any('/lookup', 'LookupController@lookup')->name('lookup')->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\LogRequest::class);
```

Middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;


class LogRequest
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

The response arrives 10 seconds earlier when I remove the `sleep(10);` So I am sure that the server waits for terminate to finish before actually returning the response.

Comment: Have you add the middleware to the list of global middlewares in your HTTP kernel ?

Comment: @Maraboc no, since I do not want it to be executed on all routes. But I added it to the route I am testing

Comment: I think that's the problem, because in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#terminable-middleware) they said `Once you have defined a terminable middleware, you should add it to the list of global middlewares in your HTTP kernel.` it will not be applied to all the routes even if you added there ;)

Comment: @Maraboc I just tried it. Now it is executed twice, and when I remove it from the route (only leaving it global) I get the same problem again (executing before sending the response)

Comment: try to replace sleep with while loop to see if the sleep causes the problem because in the doc it will be triggered after responding !!

Comment: Same problem. Still no answer. The docs are lying!